# Easy to install AngularJs charting

Tags: charts, angularjs

Must not require the use of any package manager, such as Bower, etc

Must have clear, simple instructions as to how to add it into my app.

I am in a great hurry to demo something. I have tried a few, but had problems to install. Charting for dummies, please ;-)

I require only histograms, all else is a bonus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried ZingChart? It meets your requirements.

1. Does not require use of a package manager: You can download directly [through GitHub](https://github.com/zingchart/ZingChart-AngularJS).
2. AngularJS charting: It is a JavaScript charting library built with vanilla JavaScript. However, the team has developed an Angular directive for developers to use. In a line, it lets you render charts simply by adding a ZingChart configuration object as a scope variable.
3. Clear instructions: The [quick start guide](https://github.com/zingchart/zingchart-angularjs/) on the GitHub page has 4 steps.

I'm on the ZingChart team, so please feel free to reach out if you have questions.

Comment: Thanks, Merrily, I have gotten `http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js`  to work. However, I will consider ZIng. I looked at it previously, found it to be expensive, but realized that there is a free version with branding. I guess that I need to check how distracting the branding is.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to recommend dangle.js. It's open-source and fairly easy to use. It includes a great guide and is based on D3.js. It uses Angular.js and does not require such applications like Bower. It includes quite a few charts including histograms.

## [Dangle.js](https://github.com/fullscale/dangle) ([open-source](https://github.com/fullscale/dangle))

> A set of AngularJS directives that provide common visualizations based on D3
>
> Dangle provides directives that allow you to create visualizations of your data. You can easily bind the result of queries to HTML elements. When the results update, your visualizations will also update. You can build powerful, interactive applications with just a few lines of HTML.
>
> Visualizations are built with SVG so they’re completely re-sizable and work perfectly across any device (desktop or mobile). Because we’re using SVG however, you will need to use a modern browser (any current browser including IE > 8).
>
> [image: Dangle.js Histogram Example]

Comment: Looks good (+1). I really like the look of D3JS, but think that I need to investigate which wrapper has the most chart types (or how to create my own directives)

Comment: Your link is broken. But I found the project at https://github.com/fullscale/dangle HOWEVER, its demo link is broken, so I am unsre if the projetc is being actively supported.  Hmm, the last commit was on March 4th, 2013   :-(

Comment: Good catch, I'm not so sure about the library anymore, I've removed the broken link.

Comment: If it is stable, then I would still use. I don't expect and new features, an do expcect to fix any bugs which I find.